# Calculate multiple step connections in GraphX on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have been looking for the GraphX on Spark documentation and I am trying to work out how to calculate all the 2 and potentially further step connections in the graph.

If I have the following structure

- A -> b
- b -> C
- b -> D

Then A is connected to C and D via B (A -> b -> C) and (A -> b -> D)

I was having a look at the connected components functions but not sure how you would extend it to this. In reality b will be a different vertex type but not sure if this has an effect or not.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated I am pretty new to GraphX

Comment: It is pretty trivial with `Graphframes`. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37417469/1560062

Comment: Thanks for the response I will definitely have a look at using graph frames. Are you aware if I can do this using what is natively included in graphx instead of graph frames?

Comment: Sure, but it is not trivial.

Comment: How big is your graph approximately?

Comment: In the order of a million+ vertices and a 100 million edges

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to use collectNeighborIds action, and then join with reversed copy of itself. I wrote some code:

```
val graph : Graph[Int, Int] = ...
val bros = graph.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Out)
val flat = bros.flatMap(x => x._2.map(y => (y, x._1)))
val brosofbros : RDD[(VertexId, Array[VertexId])]= flat.join(bros)
.map(x => (x._2._1, x._2._2))
.reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
```

Finally '*brosofbros*' contains vertex id and all its second neighbors, in you example it would be [A, Array[C, D]]. (but there is not B vertex)